# Synonym request: [aspnet-core] into [asp.net-core]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[aspnet-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspnet-core) refers to the [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) tag.

It had about 9 questions which I have already edited over to the correct tag.

A synonym request has been made here

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-core/synonyms

for votes on whether the synonym is valid.

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Comment: the [aspnet-core] tag should have been already deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I removed all the offending post from the synonym tag, it appears that it was removed/deleted since I first made the synonym request

I consider this request resolved as the tag no longer applies.

*Update*

Although the tag itself was deleted, the suggested synonym was still automatically approved when it received the required up-votes.

This means that this synonym request has been satisfied.

Comment: FYI, shortly after you posted this question, another question was added to the synonym tag which I removed while voting for the synonym.

Comment: Noted, and thank you for the FYI